# How to automatically add module id using Require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Image that I have so many JavaScript models, libs or some other modules, I don't add any module name for these modules.

However, if I have merged these files into one, is there any methods to add the module name to every module depending on the location of the JavaScript file, so I can require it by its name.

---edit

if my app directory looks like below:

```
js
   lib
       jquery.js
       backbone.js
       ...
   core
   models
       m1.js
       ...
pages
    template
        header.js
        footer.js
        page.js
        ...
```

I want to merge all files(including JS Modules, client-side jade template, models, etc.) into one files, how can I do that?

thanks,

kz

Comment: It's recommended to use the official optimizer (`r.js`) for merging the project into a single file: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename ; it automatically generates modules names.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.Yep, it could satisfy my requirements. But I want to merge all files into one file(including js module, jade client-side template, models, views etc.), if they don't have any dependencies, how can I do that?